# When mouse hovering, How to i get Parent element in my custom tooltip class in WinUI C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, uwp, winui-3, winui

In my custom RibbonScreenTip class I have to handle the event as ToolTip.Opened.

```
public class RibbonScreenTip : ToolTip
{
     public RibbonScreenTip ()
     {
       DefaultStyleKey = typeof(RibbonScreenTip);
       this.Opened += CustomToolTip_Opened;
     }

     private void RibbonScreenTip _Opened(object sender, object e)
     {
         FrameworkElement parent = this.PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement;

         if (parent != null)
         {
         }
     }
}
```

I have written a separate style for my custom control tooltip class.

In my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Font">
    <ribbon:RibbonButton >
         <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
             <ribbon:RibbonScreenTip  Title="Button" Placement="Top"   Description="used to control process"/>
         </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </ribbon:RibbonButton>
</ribbon:RibbonGroup>
```

I have tried to get parent in my RibbonScreenTip class opened event:

```
       FrameworkElement parent = this. PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement;
```

```
       DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
```

I have attached the RibbonScreenTip to a RibbonButton. But, RibbonScreenTip.Parent is still shown as null. Please help me.

I tried the below step first. It works fine.
but , I have to do it separately for each button.

```
namespace ToolTipTests;

public class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Source),
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            typeof(CustomToolTip),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.Opened += CustomToolTip_Opened;
    }

    public FrameworkElement Source
    {
        get => (FrameworkElement)GetValue(SourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    private void CustomToolTip_Opened(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Source is FrameworkElement parent)
        {
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
}
```

My MainWindow.xaml like:

```
<Button
    x:Name="ButtonControl"
    Content="Click">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <local:CustomToolTip
            Content="?"
            Placement="Top"
            Source="{x:Bind ButtonControl, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

If any other solution for get parents without this Dependency Property?

Comment: When mouse hovering only events about pointer will be triggered like `PointerEntered`. Maybe you could try to handle pointer for the button so you could directly get the button instead of doing this in the tooltip. But this will be complicated as well because you still need to do this for every button.

Comment: It's okay. Please provide your solutions in code or provide solution instructions.Please help me

Comment: Here is [PointerEntered sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs?view=winrt-22621#examples) for you reference. you need to save the button when `PointerEntered` occurs into a global value and clean the  global value when `PointerExited `. then you can use the button which mouse is pointing with the global value when CustomToolTip_Opened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no better solution to this given that the ToolTip is rooted inside the popup layer and there doesn't seem to be a property that makes this easier for you. You could use the [Tooltip.PlacementTarget property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice.placementtargetproperty?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2#microsoft-ui-xaml-controls-tooltipservice-placementtargetproperty) which would allow you to not have your own property but   use an existing property, however you would still need to bind your control to that property.

Answer (score 0):

As @Junjie mentioned, you could save the target button when the cursor enter the button.

Code:

```
 public Button _targetButton { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Content = "Clicked";
    }

    private void myButton_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //remove the button when pointer left
        _targetButton = null ;
    }

    private void myButton_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //save the button which pointer enters
        _targetButton = (Button)sender;
    }
```